# Attask- journal entry change for task owner change

Tags: attask

When assignee is added, we see journal entry updated. When only task owner is changed; is there a way to know from journal entry ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. There is no such field as Task Owner in workfront.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through a journal entry. It will only show assignment change but there is no way to determine if the primary assignment has changed.

Answer (score -1):

Field 'assignedToID' in Task displays Task Owner, although there could be multiple Assignments to a single task.

below Api call returns all the assignments(all the users assigned to that task)
/attask/api/TASK/55192......5d9?fields=assignments

Task Owner or primary assignee ID is returned by this api
/attask/api/TASK/55192......5d9?fields=assignedToID

But if there is a change in the Task owner only; is there a way to know from the task's journal Entry ? or any other way

.../attask/api/jrnle/search?entryDate_Sort=desc&entryDate_Mod=gte&objObjCode=OPTASK&objID=55bb........04&entryDate=2015-08-04T11%3A04%3A00%3A000%2B0000&fields=*